# Hbase Performance Tuning

Tags: hbase, ycsb

I have a following Hardware configuration for my 6 Node Hbase Cluster (1 Master - 5 Slaves)

Configuration of Each Node

2.4Ghz, 48 Core Intel CPU

256GB RAM

1Gb/ps Network Connectivity

30 x SSD Disks (JBOD Setup)

OS: RHEL 6.6

Hbase Version:1.2.0

CDH Distribution: 5.7.0

I have tuned following Parameters in Hbase:

```
hbase.client.write.buffer: 64MB


hbase.regionserver.handler.count: 64

master_region_java_heapsize: 125GB




hbase.client.scanner.caching: 10000

hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size:  8GB


hbase.hregion.max.filesize:100GB
```

With this setup I am able to get 85000 IOPS with 50% Read and 50% Writes using YCSB at 250 Threads.

Can anyone suggest me any configuration changes that will help me in generating more IOPS.

Answer (score 1):

Having more details about your setup would help. (Distribution, OS, State of the cluster, Storage etc)

Also, Is your goal just better numbers in ycsb.

Skimming through your configuration, I feel that if you have fast storage (ssd, ramdisk or so), the network is going to be saturated.

In general advice, I'd say stick to basics.

- Have good monitoring in place for the resources
- Identify and understand the bottlenecks
- Optimize

Here are some content which might help you :

I hope you have read through the official docs on performance, if not [1].

There is a nice writeup on tuning the JVM (GC specifically) for HBase. [2] [3] [4]

There is an interesting performance comparison in apache HBase blog between HDD, SSD and RAM disk. [5]

[1] https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#performance

[2] http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/12/tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-hbase/
[3] https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/06/18/part-1-tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-hbase
[4] http://product.hubspot.com/blog/g1gc-tuning-your-hbase-cluster

[5] https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/hdfs_hsm_and_hbase_part

[6] Bonus video! - https://vimeo.com/127778854